# How to test FastAPI routers with dependecies using pytest?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, fastapi

I'm struggling to understand how to write unit test for routers with dependecies.

When I test for example CitiesRepository (Service/Class with crud methods) im doing it like that:

```
@pytest.fixture
def mock_postgres_async_session():
    yield Mock(spec=AsyncSession)

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_cities_success(city_object, 
                                mock_postgres_async_session):
    cities_repository = CitiesRepository(mock_postgres_async_session)

    mock_result = Mock()
    mock_result.all.return_value = [city_object]
    mock_postgres_async_session.scalars.return_value = mock_result

    cities = await cities_repository.get_cities()

    assert isinstance(cities, list)
    city = cities[0]
    assert isinstance(city, City)
    assert city.id == 1
    assert city.name == "city_name"
    assert isinstance(cities[0].sensors, list)
    sensor = cities[0].sensors[0]
    assert isinstance(sensor, Sensor)
    assert sensor.id == 1
    assert sensor.name == "sensor_name"
    assert sensor.unit == "unit_name"
```

So the scenario is:

1. Create mock database session.
2. Determine what the database will return durning session.
3. Verify that if the database returns certain values, the function will respond correctly.

**But what specifically needs to be mocked when testing a router function that has a database session as a dependency, and which passes that session to the CitiesRepository class and then calls the CitiesRepository.get_cities() method?**

**Should I somehow mock CitiesRepository.get_cities() method?**

Here is example router that I'm struggling with:

````
router = APIRouter()

@router.get("/cities")
async def get_cities(async_session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    try:
        cities_repository: CitiesRepository = CitiesRepository(async_session)
        cities = await cities_repository.get_cities()
        cities_list = []
        for city in cities:
            city_data = {
                "id": city.id,
                "city_name": city.name,
                "sensor_list": [sensor.id for sensor in city.sensors]
            }
            cities_list.append(city_data)
        return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK, content=jsonable_encoder({"cities":cities_list}))
    except PostgreSQLNotFoundError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail=str(e))
    except PostgreSQLDatabaseError as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Unspecified error occured: {e}")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Unspecified server error.")```
````

Comment: My initial suggestion; there is no need to mock anything. The test is simple, can run fast and doesn't do a lot of work. Mocking is a good thing when you can't represent the dependency in a very testable way. The database is fast, and you want to confirm that the queries you're making and handling in your controller actually work all the way through the stack. I also recommend making CitiesRepository the dependency, not the database session - and you can handle the exceptions on an app level by registering exception handlers for those exceptions if necessary.

Comment: @MatsLindh I think that making CitiesRepository dependency instead of client/session is not a good idea. This would force me to build new database client every single time someone sends request to endpoint, which would affect performance.

Comment: Your `get_cities_repository` function would depend on the `async_session` as you do in this case, then create the repository for you. Your controller would no longer have to handle the session itself, just request a cities repository to use.

Answer (score 1):

```py
// some_file_with_dependency_fn.py
def some_dependency():
    ...

// test_something.py
from main import app
from some_file_with_dependency_fn import some_dependency

def override_some_dependency():
    ...

app.dependency_overrides[some_dependency] = override_some_dependency
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue like that:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
from app.database.postgresql.session.get_session import get_session
from unittest.mock import Mock
import pytest
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from app.schema.schema import City
from app.schema.schema import Sensor


client = TestClient(app)

async def override_dependency_success():
    mock_postgres_async_session = Mock(spec=AsyncSession)
    mock_result = Mock()
    mock_result.all.return_value = [City(id=1, name="city_name", sensors=[Sensor(id=1, name="sensor_name", unit="unit_name")])]
    mock_postgres_async_session.scalars.return_value = mock_result
    return mock_postgres_async_session

app.dependency_overrides[get_session] = override_dependency_success

@pytest.mark.asyncio
async def test_get_cities_success():
    response = client.get("/cities")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    data = response.json()
    assert "cities" in data
    assert isinstance(data["cities"], list)
```

**But i don't think that it is good and elegant solution, so if you know better, more elegant way to do it please assist.**

Comment: What in this solution isn't elegant in your opinion?

Comment: @PeterK for every endpoint I need to write seperate function to mock different session result.

Comment: Is `mock_result.all.return_value = [City(id=1, name="city_name", sensors=[Sensor(id=1, name="sensor_name", unit="unit_name")])]` the line that mostly changes? If so, you can make a parametrized function that would receive the returned value as the argument. This way you can reuse the same function in multiple tests. Let me know if this is the case and if you want a more detailed answer.